# React Component Undefined in Browser - ES6 Imports/Exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

All pages in my app render perfectly. I've just added another page called the Lightning page which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

class LightningPage extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(<h1>Hello!</h1>)
  }
}

export default LightningPage;
```

I then have an index.js file which has the following:

```
export { deafult as LightningPage } from './LightningPage.js'
```

I then import it into my App.js like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Header } from './header'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router'
... Import other page components ...
import { LightningPage } from './lightning'

const contentDivStyle = {
  padding: "1rem"
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div id='content' style={contentDivStyle}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/lightningCounter" component={LightningPage} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            ... Other routes ...
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

For clarity my folder structure is:

```
/src
--/lightning
----index.js
----LightningPage.js
  ... Other Component folders ...
--App.js
```

When I view '.../lightningCounter' in my browser I see nothing and from the react developer console I can see that the component prop for Route is undefined. If I change the component to another (eg. Home) it displays. If I move my LightingPage component into the src/ root and modify the import ({ LightningPage } => LightningPage) it works aswell. What am I doing wrong here?

I used the create-react-app and the included npm scripts. Production build does not differ from development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index.js file:

```
export { deafult as LightningPage } from './LightningPage.js'
```

Should be:

```
export { default as LightningPage } from './LightningPage.js'
```